# Warning when changing controlled input value in React

Tags: reactjs, input

I'm making a little blog in React and I have a problem updating the state on input change event.

The warning is:

> Warning: A component is changing a controlled input of type text to be
>   uncontrolled. Input elements should not switch from controlled to
>   uncontrolled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or
>   uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component

This is my code:

**Constructor:**

```
constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            id: '',
            post: {
                title: '',
                slug: '',
                content: ''
            }
        }

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

    }
```

**handleChange function**

```
handleChange(event) {
        const target = event.target;
        const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
        const name = target.name;

        this.setState({
            post: {
                [name]: value
            }
        });
    }
```

**input render:**

```
render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <AdminMenu />
                <div id="admin-post-form">
                    <div className="input-group vertical">
                        <label>Título</label>
                        <input
                            name="title"
                            placeholder="Título"
                            type="text"
                            value={this.state.post.title}
                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div className="input-group vertical">
                        <label>Slug</label>
                        <input
                            name="slug"
                            placeholder="Slug"
                            type="text"
                            value={this.state.post.slug}
                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                        />
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

What's wrong with my code ? The field is updated, but I get that warning.

Thanks!

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This:

```
    this.setState({
        post: {
            [name]: value
        }
    });
```

will replace `this.state.post` completely with an object that only has a single key. For example, if `name` is `slug`, you will replace `post` with `{ slug: 'something' }`.

As a result, if you edit one field, all other fields will become `undefined`. React treats `value={undefined}` as an [uncontrolled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) and warns you.

To fix the issue, **you probably want to merge `post` updates with the existing object instead of replacing it:**

```
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        post: {
            ...prevState.post,
            [name]: value
        }
    }));
```

Comment: Is prevState a built-in function or a reserved keyword?

Answer (score 1):

Your set state is resetting the whole `post` object. You likely want to do something like:

```
this.setState({
    post: {
        ...this.state.post
        [name]: value
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solved** using spread operator, this is the updated handleChange function that works with nested property:

```
handleChange(event) {
        const target = event.target;
        const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
        const name = target.name;

        var post = {...this.state.post}
        post[name] = value;
        this.setState({post});
    }
```